# Project root based relative paths for NodeJS modules

Tags: node.js, package, relative-path

Dealing with module inclusion in my NodeJS projects I always struggle a bit in the way of specifying paths to other module files of the project to be required.

I obviously use relative paths. But this implies doing things like:

```
const helper = require("../../lib/util/helpers.js
```

This has some drawbacks:

1. I always need to take in account where the file from which I requiring another module is placed.
2. As the project grows I occasionally need to move some files to another place due to project restructuring so I need to review not only paths from files requiring it, but also the paths of all modules required in the file I am moving.

I always thought it would be much clearer if I could specify paths relative to the project root instead of the file itself. To be clear, that is where my `package.json` file (or `node_modules` directory) is placed.

I know I can resolve the path of any external module using `require.resolve()` and I though I could do something like `path.dirname(path.dirname(path.dirname(require.resolve('express'))))` but it seems too dirty to me.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there isn't any `require.modules_path` or `require.projectRoot` property so I need to rely on some trick like that I mentioned above or traversing the whole tree up to the first parent directory containing a `package.json` file.

My question is: Is there any better solution which I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I approached an, even not perfect, acceptable solution by using a runtime Symbol to store project's root path as a property of the `process` object.

> Using a symbol to name that property we avoid any possibility of
>   colliding with another `process` object properties, even with future
>   ones.

What I did was simply adding this two lines to my `app.js` (which in Express projects is placed in project root directory and required from the main app entry point `bin/www` where I also ensured it is the first required dependency):

```
const $root = Symbol.for("projectRoot");                                         │     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
process[$root] = __dirname;
```

After that, the only thing I need to do in all other modules is to repeat the first row at the very beginning:

```
const $root = Symbol.for("projectRoot");
```

...and use it in all *require* statements. For example:

```
const helper = require(process[$root]+"/lib/util/helpers.js
```

Maybe it is far from perfect, but it works for me...